# How to print the output of a shell script in Jenkins and parse its results?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

## My Problem

Consider Jenkinsfile with the following line:

```groovy
sh('sudo -E make upload')
```

The script prints a lot of debug data, and its last output line is the destination URL, which I'd like to use at the next stage.

If I run `sh` with no arguments, I can't fetch the results. If I run it with `returnStdout: true`, I get the result but the debug lines are not printed on-the-go.

## My Question

**How can I print the output of a shell script when it is executed on Jenkins, and access its standard output as a string?**

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Use [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) on the first command, and read the output file.

```groovy
sh ('sudo -E make upload | tee url')
url = sh (script: 'tail -1 url | grep "^https://.*$"', returnStdout: true).trim()
```

## How it works

`tee` redirects the standard output of `make upload` to the standard output *and* a file called `url`. The output is printed on the screen normally, so it is visible on Jenkins UX. The second command extracts the desired output from `url`.

Comment: This solution is dangerous: Failure from `sudo -E make upload` will not cause jenkins to fail. Better append `; exit \${PIPESTATUS[0]}"` to the shell pipelines: `sh ('sudo -E make upload | tee url; exit \${PIPESTATUS[0]}')`

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
sh (script: 'sudo -E make upload', returnStdout: true).readLines().last()
```

But you might need to whitelist this if you run in the Groovy sandbox.